# How To Use Maps And Keys

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to give names to some variables. I'm getting error with this code:

```
var a2 = "SquareA2";
var squareArr:Object  = {
    a2: {
        piece: wp1_txt,
        pieceLoc: {  
            x: "-3",
            y: "297"
        }
    }
}
addChild(squareArr.a2.piece);
trace(squareArr["SquareA2"]); // this outputs undefined
```

Comment: with this var a2 = "SquareA2";  then a2 is a String variable with value "SquareA2"

Answer (score 2):

There is **not** a property in your `squareArr` Object called "SquareA2". It's important to note that the properties of an object are identified by strings. If you want to access the `a2` property of your `squareArr` you can do this:

```
trace(squareArr["a2"]);
```

**Or** if you wanted to use a string value you could set your String a2 to this:

```
var a2 = "a2";
```

**Then** you can access the property using that variable:

```
trace(squareArr[a2]);
```

**Lastly** if you had a property named `SquareA2` in your `squareArr` Object like so:

```
var squareArr:Object  = {
    a2: {
        piece: wp1_txt,
        pieceLoc: {  
            x: "-3",
            y: "297"
        }
    },
    SquareA2: "hello I'm the property value of SquareA2"
}
```

**Then** `trace(squareArr["SquareA2"]);` would have worked.